# R's top_n returns messed up ordering

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, seurat

## My final question is at the bottom

---

---

---

Hello, I am using Seurat and following along with the guided clustering tutorial. At a certain point they used this to identify the "top10" markers.

```
seurat.cm.markers %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  top_n(n = 10, wt = avg_log2FC) -> top10
```

well when I run this, and filter for my 7th cluster I get the following genes

```
[1] PATL2        HBQ1         GDF15        GPRC5A       LOC101927023 UCHL1        UCA1         SP6          TEX14        DHDH
```

I also wanted just the top 4 genes so I did the following

```
seurat.cm.markers %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  top_n(n = 4, wt = avg_log2FC) -> top4
```

and got
`[1] PATL2 UCA1  SP6   TEX14`

Well immediately this is strange, because these genes are in my top10, but they are out of order!

Looking at the raw data sorted by "avg_log2FC" it looks like (I only include a bit, it is fairly large)

```
               myAUC avg_diff power avg_log2FC pct.1 pct.2 cluster         gene
PATL2.1        0.836 3.280915 0.672   4.733359 0.713 0.053       7        PATL2
UCA1           0.551 3.047683 0.102   4.396877 0.115 0.014       7         UCA1
SP6            0.548 3.040640 0.096   4.386716 0.103 0.007       7          SP6
TEX14          0.545 2.614065 0.090   3.771299 0.115 0.026       7        TEX14
GDF15          0.728 2.378089 0.456   3.430857 0.483 0.031       7        GDF15
LOC101927023   0.565 2.359412 0.130   3.403912 0.138 0.008       7 LOC101927023
UCHL1.4        0.553 2.327770 0.106   3.358262 0.322 0.243       7        UCHL1
GPRC5A         0.616 2.160828 0.232   3.117416 0.264 0.034       7       GPRC5A
DHDH           0.535 2.147766 0.070   3.098571 0.103 0.036       7         DHDH
HBQ1.5         0.757 2.125981 0.514   3.067142 0.621 0.120       7         HBQ1
STAM-AS1       0.553 2.089224 0.106   3.014114 0.126 0.019       7     STAM-AS1
RMRP           0.601 2.059549 0.202   2.971300 0.264 0.063       7         RMRP
ALMS1-IT1      0.607 2.056665 0.214   2.967141 0.241 0.026       7    ALMS1-IT1
CACNA1A        0.541 2.040842 0.082   2.944312 0.115 0.033       7      CACNA1A
CLIC6          0.560 2.013138 0.120   2.904344 0.126 0.006       7        CLIC6
ACKR2          0.550 1.966553 0.100   2.837137 0.115 0.015       7        ACKR2
DLG4           0.547 1.943871 0.094   2.804413 0.126 0.034       7         DLG4
PADI2.6        0.790 1.920843 0.580   2.771191 0.655 0.079       7        PADI2
DMTN.1         0.684 1.901438 0.368   2.743195 0.425 0.059       7         DMTN
STX1B          0.523 1.895408 0.046   2.734496 0.103 0.058       7        STX1B
SMIM17         0.523 1.863906 0.046   2.689048 0.103 0.056       7       SMIM17
ADORA2B        0.546 1.858335 0.092   2.681010 0.138 0.046       7      ADORA2B
ALAS2.4        0.827 1.857076 0.654   2.679194 0.862 0.289       7        ALAS2
SNHG10.1       0.636 1.845172 0.272   2.662021 0.460 0.193       7       SNHG10
DUOX2.4        0.784 1.844985 0.568   2.661751 0.678 0.113       7        DUOX2
BISPR          0.643 1.825914 0.286   2.634237 0.299 0.014       7        BISPR
GYPA.3         0.841 1.823426 0.682   2.630647 0.839 0.224       7         GYPA
MYOT.2         0.769 1.807730 0.538   2.608004 0.621 0.083       7         MYOT
CYP4F35P.1     0.595 1.803768 0.190   2.602287 0.218 0.028       7     CYP4F35P
SLC6A16        0.558 1.793821 0.116   2.587937 0.138 0.021       7      SLC6A16
POU2F2         0.548 1.786269 0.096   2.577041 0.126 0.032       7       POU2F2
HBM.5          0.913 1.785719 0.826   2.576248 1.000 0.383       7          HBM
FAM78B         0.549 1.760832 0.098   2.540343 0.103 0.006       7       FAM78B
SLC41A2        0.542 1.746351 0.084   2.519452 0.126 0.044       7      SLC41A2
SLC4A1.4       0.842 1.742936 0.684   2.514525 0.805 0.165       7       SLC4A1
USH1C.4        0.758 1.732955 0.516   2.500125 0.621 0.110       7        USH1C
KCTD1.3        0.771 1.728671 0.542   2.493945 0.678 0.152       7        KCTD1
DYNLL2         0.543 1.701560 0.086   2.454832 0.115 0.029       7       DYNLL2
CYB5D2.1       0.675 1.690771 0.350   2.439267 0.678 0.331       7       CYB5D2
RNF144A-AS1.1  0.538 1.680441 0.076   2.424364 0.138 0.064       7  RNF144A-AS1
ETNPPL         0.547 1.665562 0.094   2.402898 0.103 0.010       7       ETNPPL
CPAMD8         0.531 1.622561 0.062   2.340861 0.103 0.042       7       CPAMD8
GAL3ST3.1      0.557 1.594533 0.114   2.300425 0.172 0.058       7      GAL3ST3
METTL7B.1      0.646 1.580550 0.292   2.280251 0.345 0.054       7      METTL7B
MYOG           0.633 1.578908 0.266   2.277883 0.322 0.058       7         MYOG
HBE1.5         0.771 1.569888 0.542   2.264870 0.724 0.355       7         HBE1
IL25           0.587 1.569190 0.174   2.263863 0.218 0.049       7         IL25
COL2A1.5       0.868 1.566259 0.736   2.259634 0.977 0.365       7       COL2A1
RHPN2.2        0.549 1.561098 0.098   2.252189 0.184 0.088       7        RHPN2
ZNF746         0.513 1.551724 0.026   2.238665 0.115 0.090       7       ZNF746
GLIS2-AS1      0.550 1.545196 0.100   2.229247 0.115 0.016       7    GLIS2-AS1
TRPM3          0.645 1.545086 0.290   2.229088 0.356 0.064       7        TRPM3
ADAMTS8.5      0.845 1.540347 0.690   2.222250 0.908 0.259       7      ADAMTS8
LINC01569      0.603 1.535256 0.206   2.214906 0.264 0.055       7    LINC01569
ZNF12.4        0.586 1.534215 0.172   2.213405 0.368 0.199       7        ZNF12
NTF4.1         0.594 1.518895 0.188   2.191303 0.253 0.067       7         NTF4
HEMGN.2        0.832 1.517243 0.664   2.188920 0.770 0.134       7        HEMGN
FBXO2          0.547 1.514886 0.094   2.185519 0.103 0.009       7        FBXO2
SEMA3B-AS1     0.586 1.468599 0.172   2.118741 0.207 0.035       7   SEMA3B-AS1
UBXN10         0.555 1.463796 0.110   2.111812 0.126 0.016       7       UBXN10
LOC100132352.2 0.563 1.463290 0.126   2.111081 0.207 0.079       7 LOC100132352
SGMS1-AS1      0.545 1.459354 0.090   2.105403 0.149 0.061       7    SGMS1-AS1
LOC100506100.1 0.569 1.458740 0.138   2.104517 0.184 0.045       7 LOC100506100
ANKRD20A5P.1   0.593 1.437884 0.186   2.074429 0.241 0.058       7   ANKRD20A5P
BCORL1         0.544 1.427675 0.088   2.059700 0.161 0.072       7       BCORL1
NFASC.1        0.617 1.427598 0.234   2.059589 0.310 0.076       7        NFASC
PITX2.4        0.813 1.426432 0.626   2.057906 0.770 0.143       7        PITX2
TMEM17         0.546 1.415979 0.092   2.042826 0.149 0.057       7       TMEM17
ZNF618.3       0.629 1.414453 0.258   2.040624 0.391 0.143       7       ZNF618
CACNA1G.4      0.656 1.411838 0.312   2.036852 0.448 0.148       7      CACNA1G
ZNF429         0.569 1.403565 0.138   2.024917 0.218 0.082       7       ZNF429
LMOD1.1        0.562 1.402275 0.124   2.023055 0.172 0.049       7        LMOD1
HBB.3          0.831 1.401574 0.662   2.022043 0.989 0.655       7          HBB
VASH2.2        0.682 1.398755 0.364   2.017977 0.437 0.076       7        VASH2
CES4A.1        0.538 1.393543 0.076   2.010458 0.115 0.039       7        CES4A
PDE4C          0.553 1.381775 0.106   1.993480 0.172 0.068       7        PDE4C
LRRC69         0.541 1.379336 0.082   1.989961 0.103 0.021       7       LRRC69
PRRG4          0.525 1.373245 0.050   1.981173 0.115 0.065       7        PRRG4
TMCC2.2        0.536 1.367096 0.072   1.972303 0.195 0.122       7        TMCC2
LOC100289230   0.573 1.362189 0.146   1.965224 0.161 0.014       7 LOC100289230
ARL4A.2        0.566 1.361591 0.132   1.964361 0.506 0.341       7        ARL4A
FLRT1          0.568 1.354993 0.136   1.954842 0.149 0.013       7        FLRT1
AHSP.4         0.921 1.350010 0.842   1.947653 1.000 0.384       7         AHSP
HBA1.4         0.869 1.339251 0.738   1.932131 1.000 0.900       7         HBA1
MBP            0.518 1.328774 0.036   1.917015 0.103 0.070       7          MBP
CFD            0.526 1.327767 0.052   1.915563 0.103 0.051       7          CFD
MMACHC         0.555 1.324688 0.110   1.911121 0.161 0.051       7       MMACHC
MAP3K9         0.565 1.316479 0.130   1.899277 0.195 0
```

---

---

---

So I am confused why the top4 ordering is correct, why the top10 ordering is incorrect, but why my top4 is included in my top10?

Let me know if I can supply anything else to help!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue using the example data given. `top_n()` gives the first 4 and 10 rows, as expected, for n = 4 or n = 10.

Comment: Is it possible `cluster` is an ordered factor and that it's outputing based on that original order?